# Start sage CLI with init.sage

Tags: python, command-line-interface, sage

So I am playing around with Sage and Python a bit.

But I always end up after changing a file with

```
CTRL-D
> sage
sage: load("init.sage")
```

is there a way to start the Sage CLI with the init-file preloaded?

or, alternatively, can I call `sage init.sage` and end up
in the Sage CLI?

Comment: If you put `init.sage` in the right place, it should always automatically load ... where did you put it?

Comment: just to be clear: I don't want it to load always only when I'm working on that project

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that would be supported, and I've never had to do this.  `sage foo.sage` would just process and do whatever that file says, but shouldn't start the CLI.  You may want to ask on sage-support@googlegroups.com or ask.sagemath.org where more Sage experts hang out.

Answer (score 2):

[The "Sage startup scripts" page in the SageMath reference manual](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/startup.html#the-init-sage-script)
mentions the `SAGE_STARTUP_FILE` environment variable which
controls which file is used as initialisation file.

If you have a file `init.sage` in directory `my_dir`, change to `my_dir` and run:

```
$ SAGE_STARTUP_FILE='init.sage' sage
```

and Sage will use this local `init.sage` file instead of the one
in your `DOT_SAGE` directory.

Illustration:

```
$ echo "print('\n   Using custom init file\n')" > my_init.sage
$ SAGE_STARTUP_FILE='my_init.sage' sage -q

   Using custom init file

sage:
```

Notes:

- `echo "stuff" > my_file` will erase and replace
  `my_file` if a file with that name is present,
- `sage -q` starts Sage in "quiet" mode, i.e. without displaying the banner.

Comment: To anyone reading this answer now, please note that the commands should read SAGE_STARTUP_FILE='my_init.sage' ./sage -q (this still gives banners) and SAGE_STARTUP_FILE='init.sage' ./sage    The ./sage is very important, if you run without it you will be prompted to download sage, different from ./sage . This method works by launching sage from the folder with sage installed, and with init.sage in that same folder. In particular, if the above solution does NOT work for you, try mine. Perhaps this answer is for a different version of sage.